# svn client/server versions

Tags: svn, version-control

If I understand correctly version of [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) defines:

- A structure repository on server
- A structure of working copy on client side
- API between client and server

Once we've install svn server, we don't touch/upgrade it.

Things are more complex on client side.

On client side (Windows) we currently use [tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/). It's version (correct me if I'm wrong) is corresponding to subversion version.

Now, we're going port our application to Linux and therefore we consider using additional svn clients (svn command line utility, Eclipse plugin and some GUI frontend).

Now the questions:

1. Is it possible several different clients will work on the same checkout code?
    If yes thus it means that I need carrefully pick up version of clients to be used,
    since each client expects a particular format/data be found in .svn directory?
2. What is the relationship between version of server and client side?
   If for example server side is 1.4 and client is 1.6, thus it means that some 1.6 
   features won't work?
3. Is it true that version of subversion client is not nessessary corresponding to the version of subverions, such as of [rapidsvn](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/) as opposed to [tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)?

Answer (score 6):

I would **strongly** not recommend that you try to use different Subversion clients against the same checkout directory, especially if those are running on different platforms (ie. across a network). Subversion does platform-specific things with line endings on text files, and if you check out on Windows and then check in the same working copy with Linux (for example), you may accidentally touch *every line of every file* by adding spurious CRLF line endings.

If you are doing cross-platform development, set up a different checkout directory on each platform where you're doing development. If you must share changes before checking in, consider using Git and the `git-svn` gateway.

Comment: Do you mean share changes between  platform specific checkout directories?

Regarding git. I found it considerable complicated compared to svn. Do git-svn requires a deep knowlage of git?

Is it possible to use git-svn as a primary svn client or only as an auxilury one, to make private branches/commits?

Comment: What I mean regarding sharing is: If you check out code into a specific directory using a Subversion client for a particular platform, be sure to check *in* that same working directory using the same client platform. Do not mix platforms with the same working directory checkout.

Comment: Regarding Git, it is possible to use git-svn as a primary Subversion client. When I need to use a Subversion repository, I do most of my day-to-day work using Git. I can make private branches, stash changes, merge/rebase private branches, and all that good stuff without having to even tell Subversion about it. When I'm ready to commit, I construct a linear history (usually not hard) and `svn dcommit` it to Subversion. However, for manipulating branches within the Subversion repository, I will usually use a Subversion client for that instead of git-svn.

Answer (score 5):

1. Working copy formats are major-version specific for the client (ie, don't try to use a 1.4 client on a WC created by a 1.6 client).
2. Theoretically, old client/new server and vice-versa are OK, but the most testing gets done on same version (1.6.x - 1.6.x) scenarios. Generally you're OK to mix client/server versions, just new features won't be available with the older part (ie, mergeinfo is not available in 1.4 client talking to a 1.5 server, and commits from a 1.4 client would be missing that info). Again, best to stick with same major version, but you can get away with differences if necessary.
3. Usually you can find the svn library version that a particular client was built against in the release notes.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close to the mark.  Working copies and repositories are always readable by new clients using the same major version, so a 1.6 client will always be able to handle an older server or working copy.

However, you do still need to be aware of the version supported by each one. Most will automatically upgrade a working copy automatically to their own version; so if you checkout using an older 1.4 client, and update it with a newer  client ( eg. the latest svn 1.6); the working copy will no longer be usable will the former.

Comment: It worth noting that the working copy upgrade happens immediately and silently. As soon as a 1.6 client looks at a 1.4 working copy, it upgrades it without telling you, and locks out all 1.4 clients.

Answer (score 1):

1. Most clients will respect the format they find in the .svn directories. That means they won't change it. If they don't support the format, you'll get an error but they shouldn't corrupt the data. If you use several different clients to update/work with the checkouts, they should create locks (so the second client will say that someone else is currently working on the checkout and stop). But to be safe, you shouldn't try this.
2. Yes, a 1.4 client can talk to an 1.6 server but the new features won't be available.
3. Usually, the client will say somewhere which server versions it supports but the clients are different projects and have their own version numbering scheme.