# Is it safe to use latest TortoiseSVN client with old server?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

My SVN server version is `1.7.6` and my current Tortoise SVN client is 1.7.10 (SVN 1.7.7). There's an upgrade available on the website. Is it safe to get the upgrades without breaking my existing archives?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508466/svn-client-server-versions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010996/will-tortoisesvn-1-7-work-properly-against-a-svn-1-6-repository

Comment: My question isn't about 1.6 repo. I am asking it's okay to upgrade clients (1.7.x) but my server remains 1.7.6